# Turn iPhone into a server programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I want to make my iPhone app display on a Mac's screen, kind of like AirPlay does with other machines. The only way I have heard to do this is, although I do not like it, turn the iPhone into a server. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do so. I also wanted to set it up in such a way that my Mac automatically detects it. I have seen a similar setup in the game Chopper 2. My Mac app will have a simple timer that fires every few seconds to look for the iPhone, in the same way that Chopper 2's "Find iPhone" button does.

Is there a simple way to turn the iPhone into a server, or start a "session" like Game Center does?

One last thing: I know it is somehow possible, because another app I have actually gives my iPhone a web address at the click of a button. It is called the Dicenomicon, if you want proof.

Comment: Couldn't you use the iPhone simulator from XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is no easy way to redirect your display to Mac, even if you made it a server of some kind.

Second, to discover or publish customized services on WLAN, you may want to refer to the samples on Bonjour:

- [CocoaHTTPServer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaHTTPServer/Introduction/Intro.html): a simple TCP/HTTP server.
- [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html): an app that discovers and connects to services of the same kind on WLAN by Bonjour.

Comment: I have a scripting language working perfectly for the display - I can c&p results from the debugger into my Mac app to make it display the whole thing. I only need answers on setting up the "link" between the devices, which you and @science9712 provided. I will let you know  what the results are.

Comment: You can make such links in form of HTTP or other protocols, with help of Bonjour. Bonjour is available on Mac, iOS, and Windows( with iTunes installed).

Comment: You have given me all the information I could ever need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "server", because there is no way to share the screen of an iPhone using the official SDK, although this is possible by jailbreaking.

It would be possible, however, to send data back and forth between the Mac and iPhone, and display the data on the iPhone, on a Mac. Using that data, you could try to recreate the interface on the Mac. All of this could be accomplished using sockets. A class that might help with that would be [cocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), which makes network programming a lot easier.

The auto-discovery of iPhones on the local network is achievable with Bonjour. Without getting into too many details, NSNetService would allow you to publish a service for your app from an iPhone, and NSNetServiceBrowser would allow you to find that service on the local network from the Mac. From the NSNetServiceBrowser, you could establish a socket connection with the iPhone.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You might want to take a look at the GameKit APIs, I know they do something similar between two iOS devices.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html